# Using static resources (such as JQuery) in jira plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, resources, jira

How to include web resources in Atlassian Jira 4.4 plugin?

atlassian-plugin.xml:

```
 <web-resource key="statistics-resources" name="statistics">
    <resource type="download" name="statistics.js" location="js/statistics/statistics.js"/>
    <dependency>jira.webresources:jira-global</dependency>
    <context>com.cs.jira.plugins.statistics-resources</context>
</web-resource>
```

statistics.js:

```
$("#projects").change(function() {
$(location).attr('href', "/jira/secure/StatisticsModuleAction!project.jspa?project=" + $(this).find("option:selected").text());});
```

Including resources in Velocity template:

```
$webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("com.cs.jira.plugins.statistics-resources")
```

When i try to call javascript function from my statistics.js, i get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function

Then i tried to include external jQuery library:

```
<web-resource key="statistics-resources" name="statistics">
    <resource type="download" name="jquery-1.8.2.js" location="js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="statistics.js" location="js/statistics/statistics.js"/>
    <dependency>jira.webresources:jira-global</dependency>
    <context>com.cs.jira.plugins.statistics-resources</context>
</web-resource>
```

i got another error in batch.js:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'handleAccessKeys'

How can i include my resources properly?

Comment: Is it necessary to use jQuery in your plugin?
You can try pure JavaScript.

Comment: I'd start with https://developer.atlassian.com/display/AUI/Getting+Started+with+AUI and https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Web+Resource+Plugin+Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AJS.toInit(function () { 
// Your code here for .js file
});
```

Should solve your problem and always refer $ function by AJS.$ as answered by Joe Douglas.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you've included your statistics resource correctly. Your problem is that Jira provides access to jquery through a different reference than the jquery standard. If you replace `$` with `AJS.$` in your javascript code it should solve your problem.